# How to make Flutter module return to native Android activity after the native Android activity launches a secondary route?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-add-to-app

I'm adding flutter to a existing Android project and everything is working fine, except one thing:

My Android project has only one Flutter module. In that Flutter module I have two routes that will be shown in different parts of the Android project:

```
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (_) => MyHomePage(),
    '/settings': (_) => _SettingsPage()
  }
```

In the Android Activity if I start a new Flutter activity with this:

```
startActivity(
            FlutterActivity
                .withCachedEngine(flutterEngineId)
                .build(this)
        )
```

It will start Flutter with the default page route (`/`) which is the expected result. Then in this Flutter page if I navigate back, it will pop the Flutter engine and navigate back to the Android Activity. Everything good for now.

But if I start a Flutter activity with a custom initial route, and then I press the back button, it will not pop the Flutter engine and navigate to the Android activity but to the initial Flutter route (in this case the `/` route).

```
    startActivity(
        FlutterActivity
            .withNewEngine()
            .initialRoute("/settings")
            .build(this)
    )
```

Why we're having this behavior if we are specifying the initial route while starting the `FlutterActivity`?

And if this is the expect behavior, then what is the best way of make it navigate to the Android activity?

Comment: Hi Pedro, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi ADALI, not yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is extract from the documentation:

If the route name starts with a slash, then it is treated as a "deep link", and before this route is pushed, the routes leading to this one are pushed also.
Even if the route was just /a, the app would start with / and /a loaded.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html

You could try re-naming your '/settings' route to 'settings'.

Answer (score 1):

Try SystemNavigator.pop() to pop the topmost flutter route

More details at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html